# Use setTimeout and if to control objects (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, settimeout

I encountered a problem when practicing Javascript. I'd like to make a square that I can click. After clicking, the square disappears and shows after 3 seconds. The code is as below.

```
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.style.display="none";
});


if (document.getElementById("box").style.display=="none"){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.display="block";
    }, 3000);
}
```

Here's a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xopobu/1/edit?html,js,output)
So how do I correct the code above? There seems to be something wrong in `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code says this:

*When* the box is clicked, hide it, but *right now*, before it has been clicked, see if it is hidden (hint: it won't be since it hasn't been clicked yet) and if it is then show it after three seconds.

---

Move the code to show it out of the `if` statement and in to the click function handler.

Get rid of the `if` statement entirely (since you know what state it will be just after it is clicked).

Comment: Thanks Quentin! I am wondering the order of the first(`document...`) and second part(`if...`) is important or not? The process of code in my mind was the square(box) would disappear after clicking it. And then _if_ this happened, it shows in 3 seconds. Could you please help me with this idea?

Comment: No. As the answer says, the function you pass to `setEventListener` determines what happens if and when the image is clicked. The code you put after it tests the state of the display *immediately* because it isn't inside that function.

Answer (score 1):

You need your timeout inside the eventlistener

```
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.style.display="none";

    setTimeout(function(){
        this.style.display="block";
    }, 3000);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this to get your result as also @quentin said.

```
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.style.display="none";
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.style.display="block";
    }, 3000);}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if you move your 3 sec timeout code into the listener:

```
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.style.display="none";

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.display="block";
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out your if statement:

```
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click",function(){
   this.style.display="none";
   setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("box").style.display="block";
   }, 3000);
});
```

The `setTimeout` function will never be set because when the page loads your "box" is not hidden...

Comment: Thanks brso05! But if I set the whole JS code like [this](http://jsbin.com/zoveta/1/edit?html,js,output). The box is originally hidden for `display: none`, but it still doesn't work. What's the problem in this code? :O

Comment: OK! So the answer is it won't work with `if`. Thanks! :)